# The iniscript feature of terraform does not work on vcloud director

Tags: vcloud-director-rest-api

I am currently learning terraform in vcloud director,
I want to customize my installation,
I work on version 3.3.1
The problem, the initscript does not work,
in version 3.3.1 we should delete this option
But I don't know the name of the replacement, can you help me
Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

the initscript option will still be available, but now it is inside of the customization part.
Documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/vmware/vcd/latest/docs/resources/vapp_vm

> initscript (Optional; v2.7+) Provide initscript to be executed when
> customization is applied.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30730288)